# How do I get my camera to go on in Pokemon go?

Tags: pokemon-go

On Pokemon go I can't seem to get off of the map. I want the screen to turn into my camera so that I can catch the Pokemon. How do I do it?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't tap Pokémon on the map? Like in the tutorial?

Comment: The camera turns on as soons as you click on the Pokemon. Is there anything blocking the camera?

Comment: The camera is only used when actively catching a pokemon. The map is always going to be there and when you tap a pokemon you can either turn AR (Augmented Reality) on or off. Turning it on activates the camera while catching pokemon, assuming you've given the app permission to do so.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a dupe. The dupe target is about switching AR mode on/off, this question is about going from the map to the screen where the pokemon appears for capture.

Answer (score 2):

You need to walk around until a pokemon pops up in the map. Then you tap this pokemon and the camera should start and show you the pokemon in augmented reality.

Those are the basics but there is actually a bit more to it, [here](http://www.ign.com/wikis/pokemon-go/How_to_Catch_Pokemon) is a further read on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

This Link shows you how to turn off AR which is most likely why your camrea isnt working. Hope this helps! 
[There's a Pokémon in the kebab store! Can I turn off augmented reality?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272643/theres-a-pok%C3%A9mon-in-the-kebab-store-can-i-turn-off-virtual-reality)

Answer (score 0):

If you started the game, it will ask if you wanted to use the camera. I don't know about the AR stuff, but if you say no to the camera question, just make a new account and start again.unless you've caught ALL the Pokemon.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to your phone setting find the apps name (pokemongo) then turn on the Camera that's it. and same procedure if you want to turn off.

Answer (score -3):

I believe you need a Gyroscope so that it senses directions and stuff.

Comment: Direction and stuff.. what stuff are they?